# Crear una variable en un data frame como un promedio de una variable de otro data frame

Tags: r, rstudio, apply, dplyr

quiero crear una variable que sea el promedio de cada 3 observaciones. Me explico: Tengo un data frame con 3 variables y 12 observaciones.

```
L<-c(1,4,5,3,4.2,3,4,4.5,4.3,2.1,2.2,5) 
K<-sample(1:20, 12,replace = T)
G<-runif(12, -2, 5)
datos<-data.frame(L,K,G)
datos2<-data.frame()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí tendríamos el data frame inicial, pero la duda es la siguiente: Quiero crear otro data frame donde la variable L de ese nuevo data frame va a ser las suma de sus tres primeras observaciones dividio en 3, y esa será su primera observación, luego, la suma de las tres siguientes dividido en 3 será su segunda y así sucesivamente hasta que el data frame quede con 4 observaciones donde estas son un promedio. Por ejemplo, para L su primera observación sería: `(1.0+4.0+5.0)/3`, la segunda sería: `(3.0+4.2+3.0)/3`, la tercera `(4.0+4.5+4.3)/3` y la última `(2.1+2.2+5.0)/3` y estas cuatro operaciones terminarían siendo la nueva columna L de un nuevo data frame que he llamado `datos2` con 4 observaciones.

Más o menos tengo una idea con la familia apply, pero ando estancado. Espero puedan ayudarme, quedo atento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Básicamente necesitas aplicar la función `mean` a grupos de 3 elementos, por lo que lo primero que tendrías que hacer, es generar estos grupos y luego aplicar la media sobre cada uno:

```
datos$grupo <-rep(1:(nrow(datos)/3), each=3) # Numeramos cada grupo de 3 filas
aggregate(L ~ grupo, datos, mean)            # aplicamos la media a cada grupo
```

Si estás familiarizado con el mundo `tidyverse` es algo parecido:

```
library(tidyverse)

datos %>% 
  mutate(grupo = rep(1:(nrow(datos)/3), each=3)) %>% 
  group_by(grupo) %>% 
  summarise(L=mean(L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que se me ocurre es crear un id para grupo de 3 filas, con la finalidad de poder agruparlas y calcular la media.

Esto usando tidyverse quedaria asi:

```
datos %>%
  mutate(id = sort(rep(1:4, nrow(datos) / 4))) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(L = mean(L, na.rm = T)) %>%
  select(-id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo la respuesta con R base.

```
# Creas un vector en donde se guardará los cálculos ---> vv
vv<-c()
for (i in seq(1,length(datos$L),3)) {
  e<-mean(datos$L[i:(i+2)])
  vv<-c(vv,e)
}
```

Al final guardas este vector `vv` en el data frame que quieres crear.

```
datos2<-data.frame(vv)

> datos2
        vv
1 3.333333
2 3.400000
3 4.266667
4 3.100000
```